# Bootstrap 3 collapse - make to collapse only one panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to have collapse panel which allow to collapse only one panel at a time. But my collapse allow to open more than one panel at the time.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="panel-group" id="h-promocje" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" style="">
<?php foreach ($promocje as $key => $promocja) { ?>
    <div class="panel-default">
        <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" role="button" style="text-decoration:none !important;" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#h-promocje" href="#promocja<?=$key?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="promocja<?=$key?>">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="h-promocja<?=$key?>" style="border-bottom: 1px solid white;padding-left: 0;padding-right: 0;">
                <h4 class="panel-title" style="color:white;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;text-transform: uppercase;padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 3px;text-align: left;">
                    <?=$promocja->tytul?>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </a>
        <div id="promocja<?=$key?>" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="promocja<?=$key?>">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?=$promocja->opis?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using Bootstrap. And Bootstrap's collapse needs declaration of `.panel` class in the collapsible structure and + use of `data-parent=""` attribute in the structure, otherwise it doesn't works as accordion.
**You haven't added the panel class, add it with panel-default class.**

```css
.container-full {
  width: 90%!important;
  /* for demo */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-full">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
          on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
          raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the live example from Bootstrap site. try removing the panel class.

Comment: Thanks. That was a problem.